# App Engine ConfigFilter: failed to load service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am trying to build a GAE java8 app with Cloud Endpoints Framework. I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management). I have set `ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME` and `ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION` in `app.yaml` and `appengine-web.xml`. I have also given my App Engine service account Editor AND Service Controller role.

Here are the logs from Logs Viewer:

```
com.google.api.control.ConfigFilter init: Failed to load service (ConfigFilter.java:94)
endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigException: Failed to fetch service config (status code 403): 
This may occur if the App Engine service account has been deleted or does not have correct permissions. Visit https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project and verify that the App Engine default service account has either the Editor or Service Controller role.
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.fetch(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:167)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.get(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:131)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.get(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:50)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Suppliers$ExpiringMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:241)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigFetcher.fetch(ServiceConfigFetcher.java:41)
    at com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter$1.load(ServiceManagementConfigFilter.java:33)
    at com.google.api.control.ConfigFilter.init(ConfigFilter.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:240)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:178)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:120)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:757)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:720)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:690)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:882)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:270)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have also tried following many other posts that recommended running `gcloud auth application-default login`. It did not fix the issue as well. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by enabling the following services:

```
gcloud services enable servicemanagement.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable servicecontrol.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable endpoints.googleapis.com
```